# Spread syntax and Typescript — supplied parameters do not match?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Looking at this simple code from [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) :

```
function myFunction(x, y, z):void { }
var args = [0, 1, 2];
myFunction(...args);
```

[— I get an error](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20myFunction(x%2C%20y%2C%20z)%3Avoid%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Avar%20args%20%3D%20%5B0%2C%201%2C%202%5D%3B%0D%0AmyFunction(...args)%3B) :

[image]

Even If I'm being super clear :

```
function myFunction(x, y, z):void { }
var args:any[3] = [0, 1, 2];
myFunction(...args:any[3]);
```

It still doesn't work.

**Question:**

Why doesn't it work and did I  miss something ?

I've already seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34181899/859154) which muted the error  via :

```
function myFunction(x, y, z):void { }
var args  = [0, 1, 2];
(<any>myFunction)(...args);
```

Why did `<any>` mute the error ?
It would've been clear if it was :

`(<any>)(myFunction(...args));` but it's not.

Comment: I have run into the same issue before. `myFunction.apply(null, args)` works.

Comment: Is that the exact code for `myFunction`? Are you sure that `x, y, z` don't have types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as TypeScript is concerned, you're passing an array to a function that takes three arguments. Thus the signature mismatch error.

Let me be clear here: What you have is **absolutely valid** ES2015 JavaScript. It's just not valid TypeScript.

`(<any>myFunction)` casts `myFunction` as, well, "anything", so TypeScript doesn't look at the function definition. `(<any>)(myFunction(...args));` would tell the compiler the result of calling `myFunction` is `any`.

Comment: But I'm passing an array which is explicitly `any[3]`

Comment: ... and? It's still an array (okay, an array of three elements, but still an array) being passed to a function that takes three separate, required, arguments.

Comment: I might be missing something but that's the job of `...args`. to "break" the array of `[0,1,2]` into `0,1,2`. So things should be fine  , no? myfunction will still get what it expectes : 3 values not as an array - but as simple arguments. just like with `.apply`

Comment: This looks pertinent: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/238

Comment: @Royi your understanding is correct: what's unclear here is how to get the TypeScript compiler to understand that and underscores the difficulty of layering types on top of extremely dynamic language features.

Comment: Why does anybody use typescript :(