# Array destructuring in parameters list, with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Using TypeScript, I am trying to figure out how to do array destructuring in the arguments list.

We can use object destructuring like so:

```
let foo = function({firstname, lastname}){...}

foo({
  firstname: 'ralph',
  lastname: 'lauren'
});
```

I am wondering if we can do the same thing with array destructuring, it would be very useful for me, something like:

```
let bar = function([desc, opts, fn]){...}

bar([
  'yes',
   {},
   function(){}
]);
```

is it possible to do this with an array with TypeScript?

Comment: Of course it is possible, why would it not? Haven't you tried it? It works since ES6.

Comment: yeah I tried it :( with TypeScript, that is

Comment: what is this called, so I google how to do it with TypeScript

Comment: Maybe you should make it a TypeScript question then and post the error message you got from the compiler. I guess the type checker doesn't like it, similar to the problem with [spread arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44682020/1048572)?

Comment: It is a TypeScript question, but I can make it clearer that it's TypeScript, can you remove the downvote, and I will fix the question.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the edit!

Comment: No it doesn't compile as is, because I need to add the type information to the array in the arguments list ([desc: string, opts: Object, fn: Function]) and when I do that, it still gives me red squigglies.

Comment: @AlexanderMills And what do the "red squigglies" say? What's the error message when you try to compile it? And please [edit] your question to show how you tried to add the type information, as *that* is what your problem is about.

Comment: There's an apparent answer to the question. Sorry it was hard to create a good description of the question. Screenshots are nice sometimes, but people seem to downvote screenshots.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Glad to see my answer helped. If I may say a bit about screenshots: they make it harder to play with the code and see what happened. It is more important for us to see the code and specific error message, rather than "red squiggles". Happy programming :)

Comment: @Jokester The OP mentions "red squigglies", not "red squiggles" - this is an important distinction as red squiggles were deprecated in TypeScript 2.8.4

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An array of fixed length and types is also called a `tuple` in TS.
We can destructure a tuple argument like:

```
let bar = function ([desc, opts, fn]: [string, {}, Function]) {


}

bar([
    'yes',
    {},
    function () { }
]);
```

Comment: What about an arbitrary length array? or destructuring the first few elements and collecting the remainder with the spread operator?