# What is the meaning of square brackets on a function parameter

Tags: typescript

Can someone explain me what is the meaning of `[]` in a function parameter, I don't get what the purpose of the `[]` on `[fileEntry]`.

```
const onDrop = ([fileEntry]: any[]) => {
     fileEntry && fileEntry.file(file => processFile(file))
}
```

Does it convert the `fileEntry` to an array? I f yes why that won't work?

```
const onDrop = (fileEntry) => {
     fileEntry = [fileEntry]
     fileEntry && fileEntry.file(file => processFile(file))
}
```

Comment: This isn't JavaScript. It's likely TypeScript or Flow.

Comment: isn't this part: `: any[]` TS?

Comment: It is an ES6 feature called "array destructuring" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688316/array-destructuring-in-parameters-list-with-typescript

Comment: Assuming you're using TS, then yes. But it might also be Flow.

Comment: `[fileEntry]` is array destructuring and `: any[]` tells typescript that it is an array where elements are of the type `any`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array destructuring in parameters list, with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688316/array-destructuring-in-parameters-list-with-typescript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's destructuring - the function takes an array as its argument and `fileEntry` is the first entry of that array.

Simpler example (JavaScript):

```js
const firstEl = ([el]) => el;

console.log(firstEl([a, b, c]));
```

> Does it convert the fileEntry to an array? I f yes why that won't work?

No, it does the opposite. So the first line of your function is backwards. This is the equivalent of the first bit of code:

```
const onDrop = (fileEntry) => {
     [fileEntry] = fileEntry
     fileEntry && fileEntry.file(file => processFile(file))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is called [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment): it declares a variable named `fileEntry` in the scope of the function, which is assigned to the first item of the function's parameter (which is supposedly an `Array`).

Note that the function's parameter may not be an `Array`. The only real requirement is the [`iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) in order to make destructuring assignment work:

```js
const func = ([first, second, third]) => first + second + third;

const obj = { [Symbol.iterator]: () => [1, 2, 3].values() };

console.log(func(obj));
```

Answer (score -1):

It is array destructuring. It means you pass it an array and it assigns a member of that array to a variable. Basically it is doing this:

```
const onDrop = (x) => {
     let fileEntry = x[0];
     fileEntry && fileEntry.file(file => processFile(file))
}
```

If there are two variables in the square brackets like:

```
const onDrop = ([fileEntry, options]) => {
     fileEntry && fileEntry.file(file => processFile(file))
}
```

It would do this:

```
const onDrop = (x) => {
     let fileEntry = x[0];
     let options = x[1];
     fileEntry && fileEntry.file(file => processFile(file))
}
```