# Spread rest with TypeScript complains about signature of call target

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function defined this way:

```
function create(element1: number, ...otherElements: any[]) {
  // Do something
  return makeSomething(...otherElements)
}


function makeSomething(a: string, b: number, c: IElements) {
  // Do something
}
```

TypeScript complains about the parameters I pass to `makeSomething`

> error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call
>   target.

What is the right way to do define such thing while still using the spread syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/34179897/6304441

Comment: @dogui This ticket refers to only number type parameters, my case is about different types passed as parameters

Answer (score 6):

One of the problems here is that Typescript has no idea how many items are in `...otherElements: any[]`. It can't guarantee there will be 3 items to pass to `makeSomething`, even though the item type (`any`) would be valid for the arguments.

You can trivially work around that by telling it there are, in fact, 3 elements:

```
function create(element1: number, ...otherElements: any[]) {
  // Do something
  const [a, b, c] = otherElements;
  return makeSomething(a, b, c)
}
```

This allows you to add defaults for missing ones, error checking, etc, but most importantly, having three explicit elements satisfies the type check.

If you want to pass the remaining arguments as well, simple add a rest parameter to the destructure:

```
function create(element1: number, ...otherElements: any[]) {
  // Do something
  const [a, b, c, ...d] = otherElements;
  return makeSomething(a, b, c, ...d)
}
```

Comment: @alexmngn How so? You're calling out that you expect three items, which allows you to safely handle errors when there aren't three items. Blindly passing the array is more of a hack, since you might be lying to `makeSomething` and things could explode later on.

Comment: typescript is a bit hacky in my opinion... (very noticeable with **normal** es6 features)